# Populate textarea field using WTForms

Tags: python, forms, flask, textarea, wtforms

As I understand it, if you want to populate a textarea you place the text between the textarea tags. However I am using WTForms. How can I pre-populate the form from views or in my template?

FORM

```
class ModuleSectionForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Section Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField('Description', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Add Section')
```

VIEW

```
@modules.route('/update_section/<name>/<title>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update_section(name, title):
    form = ModuleSectionForm()
    module = Module.objects(title=name).first()
    section = None
    for sect in module.sections:
        if sect.title == title:
            section = sect
    #if form.validate_on_submit():
        #save data 
    return render_template('modules/update_section.html', section=section, form=form)
```

TEMPLATE

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('modules.update_section', name=name) }}">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.title.label(class="form-control-label") }}
        {{ form.title(class="form-control", value=section.title) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.description.label(class="form-control-label") }}
        {{ form.description(class="form-control", default=section.description) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-secondary shadow") }}
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by just assigning the text to display beforehand (in the view, for instance).

Try edit your view (`update_section`) this way:

```
+ form.description.data = 'text you want to display'
```

And your template as follows:

```
- {{ form.description(class="form-control", default=section.description) }}
+ {{ form.description(class="form-control") }}
```

Mind you, there's an alternative way, which is to specify the placeholder attribute (but I guess is not what you want to do here).

Answer (score 1):

Typically with WTForms (let's assume you're using Flask and Bootstrap here), you'll use the `value` attribute of the input to pre-populate a form field.   Note that pre-populating a field is distinct from providing a 'placeholder', which is just an ephemeral hint.    So usually we pre-populate like this:

```
<div class="form-group row">
 <label for="form_subject" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Subject</label>
 <div class="col-sm-7">
  <input class="form-control" id="form_framework" name="form_framework"
value="{{ instruct.Subject }}">
 </div>
</div>
```

With Flask and Bootstrap, the `name` attribute is required to pass the value back to the Controller upon submission, the `value` attribute is used to pre-populate the field from the object - in this case, our controller has passed in an object called instruct, which has an attribute `Subject`.

But you have to be aware that different kinds of inputs in WTForms have different attributes, and this is left as a fun challenge for the developer to figure out.

For example, in a drop-down, the syntax is like this:

```
 <option selected="selected">{{ someValue }}</option>
```

Where we assume that `someValue` has been passed to the template from the controller.

TextArea doesn't have a `value` attribute, so in order to pre-populate the field, you do it a bit more like with a drop-down, you have to provide the value between the tags, like so (again, using Bootstrap here in case any of these tags are unfamiliar):

```
<div class="form-group row">
 <label for="form_longish_text"
class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Longish Text</label>
 <div class="col-sm-7">
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" 
id="form_longish_text"
name="form_longish_text">{{ instruct.LongishText }}
  </textarea>
 </div>
</div>
```

One thing to remember - `<textarea>` will respect whatever spaces you might have in your template, so your code should generally put both sides of the tag on one line.   (e.g. `<textarea>some text</textarea>`)   This is relevant if it's important that no extra spaces or new lines are added to your value.